# Getting files for Yesterday on Unix/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting, scp

I have a problem with my script when i want to get only yesterday files format date and days is like this 20150513_1300 .
So am using this script but it's not working.

```
#!/bin/bash
YESTERDAY=`TZ=GMT+24 date +%Y%m%d_%H%m`
scp usename@xx.yy.xy.y:/var/opt/fds/statistics/*ExtendedStatistic.$YESTERDAY_.stat /SystemOM/
```

Comment: I`m missing what you want  to copy in scp command "scp what system:where"

Answer (score 2):

`$YESTERDAY_` is probably not set. Instead try:

```
scp usename@xx.yy.xy.y:/var/opt/fds/statistics/*ExtendedStatistic.${YESTERDAY}_.stat /SystemOM/
```

Comment: thank you leu i just try it it's not working but what's the mean of {} ?

Comment: when you use variable in string you must it separate by {} how leu show you

Comment: {} asure to pick the variable `YESTERDAY`. `YESTERDAY_` is another valid variable name, which in your case might be unset.